# Override/kill when Code 3/SQLSTATE=57016 Occurs

Tags: db2, error-handling

I have encountered issues a few times when a process of mine performs a bulk load to a temp table we use for pre-processing purposes. The Bulk load fails for one reason or another (this we are looking into and addressing separately), and then the table that we were bulk loading to gets locked up. Quiesce/Unquiesce and even restarting DB2 are not releasing the lock on this table.

Here is a screenshot of the error in question that we receive every time:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the error in question]

This error code means **The table is in the "Load Pending" state. A previous LOAD attempt on this table resulted in failure. No access to the table is allowed until the LOAD operation is restarted or terminated.**

Is there any command or way to circumvent this or regain access to this specific table? We have many other processes running when this bulk load runs so restarting DB2 is a very undesirable option and, in our case right now, has not freed up the table.

Apologies if this is not enough information to go off of, please let me know what else I should provide if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LOAD` was interrupted so the table was placed into a `LOAD PENDING` state. To take it out of the `LOAD PENDING` state you will need to issue one of the following:

- `LOAD TERMINATE` to roll back the operation
- `LOAD REPLACE` to reload the entire table
- `LOAD RESTART`

Also, do not take a backup before you take the table out of `LOAD PENDING` state.

See [Restarting an interrupted load operation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0004594.html) in Information Center for details.

Answer (score -4):

Try below command in db2 command line

```
db2 REORG TABLE [SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: Do you have any reasons why this would be a better solution than the one accepted several years ago?